# How to show horizontal lines at tips of error bar plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, errorbar

I can generate an error-bar plot using the code below. The graph produced by the code shows vertical lines that represent the errors in `y`. I would like to have horizontal lines at the tips of these errors ("error bars") and am not sure how to do so.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10, dtype=int)
y = 2**x
yerr = np.sqrt(y)*10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr, solid_capstyle='projecting')
ax.grid(alpha=0.5, linestyle=':')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

The code generates the figure below. I've played with the `solid_capstyle` kwarg. Is there a specific kwarg that does what I am trying to do?
[image: Error Plot]

And as an example of what I'd like, the figure below:

[image: example solution]

In case it's relevant, I am using matplotlib 2.2.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The argument you are looking for is `capsize=` in [`ax.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html). The default is `None` so the length of the cap will default to the value of  `matplotlib.rcParams["errorbar.capsize"]`. The number you give will be the length of the cap in points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10, dtype=int)
y = 2**x
yerr = np.sqrt(y)*10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr, solid_capstyle='projecting', capsize=5)
ax.grid(alpha=0.5, linestyle=':')
plt.show()
```

[image]