# How to make horizontal error bars instead of vertical in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created error bars via matplotlib, however, I want them to be horizontally instead of vertically.

```
ax.errorbar(x, y, deviation, fmt='bo')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the current state of the error bar is, but [https://gist.github.com/suntong/8740c0b6a67cfc79856b](https://gist.github.com/suntong/8740c0b6a67cfc79856b) or  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114997/how-to-show-horizontal-lines-at-tips-of-error-bar-plot-using-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114997/how-to-show-horizontal-lines-at-tips-of-error-bar-plot-using-matplotlib) might help.

Comment: @r-beginners I meant I want to make the error bars horizontally, not just add the horizontal tips. I have a scatter plot and when the error bars are vertically it overlaps other points so I want them to appear horizontally instead.

Comment: I read the comments and still did not understand them, so I suggest you post the current output. Also, it would be nice to have the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide xerr attribute `matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar(x, y, xerr)`

xerr: Define the horizontal error bar sizes.

**xerr, yerr : float or array-like, shape(N,) or shape(2, N), optional**

The errorbar sizes:

- scalar: Symmetric +/- values for all data points.
- shape(N,): Symmetric +/-values for each data point.
- shape(2, N): Separate - and + values for each bar. First row contains the
- lower errors, the second row contains the upper errors.
- None: No errorbar.